# How to generate random number with a large number of decimals in Python?

Tags: python, random, numbers

How it's going?

I need to generate a random number with a large number of decimal to use in advanced calculation.

I've tried to use this code:

```
round(random.uniform(min_time, max_time), 1)
```

But it doesn't work for length of decimals above 15.

If I use, for e.g:

```
round(random.uniform(0, 0.5), 100)
```

It returns 0.586422176354875, but I need a code that returns a number with 100 decimals.

**Can you help me?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 100 decimals

The first problem is how to create a number with 1000 decimals at all.

This won't do:

```
>>> 1.23456789012345678901234567890
1.2345678901234567
```

Those are floating point numbers which have limitations far from 100 decimals.

Luckily, in Python, there is the [`decimal` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) which can help:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1.2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901')
Decimal('1.2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901')
```

Decimal can have any precision you need and it won't introduce [floating point errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19473770/389289), but it will be much slower.

### random

Now you just have to create a string with 100 decmals and give it to `Decimal`.

This will create one random digit:

```
random.choice('0123456789')
```

This will create 100 random digits and concatenate them:

```
''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for i in range(100))
```

Now just create a `Decimal`:

```
Decimal('0.' + ''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for i in range(100)))
```

This creates a number between 0 and 1. Multiply it or divide to get a different range.

Comment: When I multiply it or divide the Decimal number created, the number of decimals is missed and it returns a number with only 15 decimals... Is that normal? What can I do?

Comment: @EduardoSampaioSoares You should configure [`decimal.Context`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#context-objects) to have higher precision. E.g. do the calculation within block `with decimal.localcontext(decimal.Context(prec=100)):`

Comment: You've helped me a lot! Thank you again!