# lose precision in small float num multiplication

Tags: python-3.x

```
hours = "40"
hourrate = "$45.07 "
```

I write the code :

```
salary = float(hours)*float(hourrate[1:-1])*52.0
```

why the result on my terminal is 93745.59999999999?
(I was handling a .csv file in python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid floating point errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Answer (score 0):

## IEEE

Floating-point is imprecise. `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`. If you need precision, look into using symbolic mathematics like the [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) module.

Comment: @HongliBu Yes, because floating-point cannot always be represented precisely by binary, so I-triple-E tries to fix it but it doesn't always work

Comment: So what's the method in python to solve this problem in float multiplication? use "round()" function?

Comment: @HongliBu For currency, you could round to the nearest 1/100, but I'd look into precise symbolic maths for larger scale projects.

Comment: but why some other operations, like float("34.23")*float("24.5") * 52.0,  are operated correctly?

Comment: @HongliBu because those numbers happen to be precise enough in binary that the slight discrepancy is corrected rather than amplified with some other cases