# Getting a different value when adding a float value in an integer (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am adding a float value in an integer using loops but the answer is different.
Here is my code:

```
import time
test = 0
while True:
    test += 0.0001
    print(test)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

When I ran it I should have got:

```
0.0001
0.0002
0.0003
0.0004
0.0005
.........
```

But I got:

```
0.0001
0.0002
0.00030000000000000003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006000000000000001
0.0007000000000000001
0.0008000000000000001
0.0009000000000000002
0.0010000000000000002
0.0011000000000000003
0.0012000000000000003
```

Why it is so and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid floating point errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the output precision  using `{:.4f}` to keep four digits .

```
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
>>> print("{}".format(pi))
3.141592653589793
>>> print("{:.3f}".format(pi))
3.142
>>> print("{:.4f}".format(pi))
3.1416
>>> print("{:.5f}".format(pi))
3.14159
```

Comment: Great . Is there any way to stop rounding off the number?

Comment: You cann't represent the float number just as exact as you want, unless you set the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You solve the problem by seeking a deeper understanding of the inexact representation of rational, base 10 numbers by base 2 hardware.

See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for a starter.

Answer (score 0):

It is inherent to the way binary floating-point are handled in operating systems. Have look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

One of the possible solutions is to round the results to the decimal you want, here round to .4.