# Calculating sum of float numbers using math.fsum() showing incorrect values

Tags: python, floating-point, sum, floating-accuracy

I am performing a simple sum operation on float numbers using `math.fsum()` function in Python but the result is not matching with what am expecting.

Please find the example below:

```
math.fsum([-5.2,-20.8,5,21])
#output : -8.881784197001252e-16
```

Ideally the output should be zero. What is the best way of calculating the sum of a list with both positive and negative float and int values? I have tried using `sum` and `fsum`. But in both the cases the outputs are not correct

```
math.fsum([-5.2,-20.8,5,21])
#output : -8.881784197001252e-16
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: And [How to avoid floating point errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `fsum` here: it's actually giving you _exactly_ the right answer in this case (with no rounding). The problem is with your input values: with decimal representations of binary floating-point (which is what Python is using under the hood), What You See Is Not What You Get. Thus the actual value stored for the numeric literal `-5.2` is, on a typical machine, `-5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125`, and similarly for `-20.8`.

Comment: Look up "catastrophic cancellation". That is what happens there.