# How to do exact decimal number calculation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

My dataframe looks something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql('select * from foo')

a  b  c
0.1 0.2 0.3
0.3 0.4 0.5
```

If I directly run `df['a'] * df['b']` the result is not exact as I expected because of float number issues.

I tried

```py
import Decimal

df['a'].apply(Decimal) * df['b'].apply(Decimal)
```

But when I inspect df['a'].apply(Decimal) with PyCharm, the column turns out to be something strange, here is just an example, not real numbers:

```py
a
0.09999999999999999
0.30000000000001231
```

I wonder how to do exact multiplication in pandas.

Comment: What do you mean by `exact multiplication`?

Comment: whats the expected output because df['a'] * df['b'] works for me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in pandas but in floating point inaccuracy: `decimal.Decimal(0.1)` is `Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')` on my 64 bits system.

A simple trick would be to first change the floats to strings, because pandas knows enough about string conversion to properly round the values:

```
x = df['a'].astype(str).apply(Decimal) * df['b'].astype(str).apply(Decimal)
```

You will get a nice Series of Decimal:

```
>>> print(x.values)
[Decimal('0.02') Decimal('0.12')]
```

So with *exact decimal* operations - which can matters if you process monetary values...