# Converting from Float to Int changed the output

Tags: python

I defined a simple `sqrt` function to calculate a square root of a given number.

```
def sqrt(n):
    low = 0
    up = n  
    for i in range(50):
        mid = float(low+up)/2
        if pow(mid,2) < n:
            low = mid
        elif pow(mid,2) > n:
            up = mid
        else:
            break
    return mid
```

When I do:

`print(sqrt(9))`

I get `3.0` as the output. However when I do:

`print(int(sqrt(9)))` I get `2`.

Could somebody please help me understand why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: When I run your first code I don't get `3.0` I get `2.9999999999999973` `int()` just cuts off the decimal and gives you `2`. Maybe `round()` would give you the results you want.

Comment: I think sqrt is already defined in python (which does the exact thing you want to do). Why are you redefining it?

Comment: If `print(sqrt(9))` printed that for you, you must be on Python 2, which is obsolete, incompatible with tons of useful libraries and features, and unsupported by the Python development team. You should really get on Python 3.

Comment: ^How did you immediately recognize that this was a Python version issue? Just curious

Comment: I've seen the same problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of rounding. Your method definition actually computes the `sqrt(9)` to be `2.9999999999999973`. However the rounding is not applied to casting, therefore the decimal is lost in the casting of `int(2.9999999999999973)`.
When you print directly, python applies rounding which brings this value up to 3.

Python 2.7 output:

```
Python 2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> def sqrt(n):
...     low = 0
...     up = n
...     for i in range(50):
...         mid = float(low+up)/2
...         if pow(mid,2) < n:
...             low = mid
...         elif pow(mid,2) > n:
...             up = mid
...         else:
...             break
...     return mid
...
>>> sqrt(9)
2.9999999999999973
>>> print(sqrt(9))
3.0
>>> print(int(sqrt(9)))
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `sqrt(9)` returns `2.9999999999999973` [1], at least in Python version `3.5` (and perhaps all versions `3.x`?). And `int` returns only the integer component of the number. That's why you get `2` as the result, as the integer component of `2.9999999999999973` is indeed `2`.

If you want to round the result to the nearest integer, you can do `round(sqrt(9))` which produces `3`.

[1] To understand why this happens and how to fix this issue, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors).

Comment: "Actually, int(sqrt(9)) returns 2.9999999999999973 for me" - uh, what?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oops, my bad, I must have typed the `int` as a typo. I've corrected the answer now.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I am using Python 2.7 and the output I get for `sqrt(9)` is `3.0`.

Comment: Output of `sqrt(9)` is unfortunately not the same as what you think `print(sqrt(9))` will print...

Comment: @MadaManu I see. I'm using Python 3.5, and did not know 2.7 treated it a little differently. I'll edit my answer to reflect the Python version.

Comment: @MadaManu, why do you say that?

Comment: `Python 2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> def sqrt(n):
...     low = 0
...     up = n
...     for i in range(50):
...         mid = float(low+up)/2
...         if pow(mid,2) < n:
...             low = mid
...         elif pow(mid,2) > n:
...             up = mid
...         else:
...             break
...     return mid
...
>>> sqrt(9)
2.9999999999999973
>>> print(sqrt(9))
3.0
>>> print(int(sqrt(9)))
2
>>>`

Comment: Sorry - pasting code on comments section is not great. I updated my answer below to see it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get converted into `int` you can use the following:

```
print(int(round(sqrt(9))))
```