# Python returns wrong result for float addition

Tags: python-3.x

```
Probabilities = \
    [0.27,
     0.33,
     0.35,
     0.03,
     0.01,
     0.007,
     0.002,
     0.0007,
     0.0002,
     0.0001]
result = 0
for probability in Probabilities:
    result += probability
print(result)
```

The output is:

> 1.0000000000000002

Why?

I also tried the `sum()` function but the result is the same.

Comment: This is due to floating point errors - look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Comment: This is explained in [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error).