# Column Multiplication in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to multiply two columns in Spark. Both the columns are of type Double.
The result of the multiplication between 26.0 and 0.001 is 0.026000000000000002 and not 0.0026.
How do I resolve this?

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- age: double (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mul: double (nullable = false)


>>> df.withColumn('res', df['age']*df['mul']).show()
+----+--------+-----+--------------------+
| age|    name|  mul|                 res|
+----+--------+-----+--------------------+
|25.0|   Ankit|0.001|               0.025|
|22.0|Jalfaizy|0.001|               0.022|
|20.0| saurabh|0.001|                0.02|
|26.0|    Bala|0.001|0.026000000000000002|
+----+--------+-----+--------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round to 4 decimals the column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn("res", F.round(F.col("res"), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert It to Float :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
table_schema = StructType([
     StructField("value", FloatType(), True)])
df= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
 ( 0.026000000000000002,)       
        ],table_schema
    )
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

These are **floating point errors**.
A simple `1.1-1.0` gives `0.10000000000000009` in Python (or in Pyspark).
You can find more information about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) or in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Rounding off to appropriate decimal places seems to be the simple solution for this problem.